# Ports in server 2016 opening sequentially instead of the port requested

Tags: c#, windows, networking, windows-server-2016

So, i've never seen anything like this before. the company i work for was having an issue with one specific piece of software not opening it's port so after some investigation we determined it appears to be just opening some arbitrary port instead of the one requested. initially i thought this was the software so i wrote a small program to just open a port:

```
server = new TcpListener(localAddr,Convert.ToInt32("81"));
server.Start();
```

regardless of what port i enter in there, it will open another port. in this specific instance i run the program asking for it to open 81. it opens 2313

`TCP    10.2.0.30:2313         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9468`

then if i just keep clicking open; which really should fail after the first time due to the port being in use, it will just keep opening ports sequentially.

```
U:\>netstat -aon | find /i "9468"
  TCP    10.2.0.30:2313         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9468
  TCP    10.2.0.30:2314         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9468
  TCP    10.2.0.30:2315         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9468
  TCP    10.2.0.30:2316         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9468
```

nothing in the code is telling it to do this, there must be something in this Windows Server 2016 somewhere that's causing this. although i have no idea why or where. i appreciate any help you can give me!

Comment: 1) Not sure why you're converting the string "81" to an int instead of just using the int literal 81. 2) Have you tried running this on another computer, like maybe your dev box to see if it has the same behavior?

Comment: A port number is a 16-bit unsigned integer, not a 32-bit integer. You are actually passing 16 bits of `0` (the first 16 bits of the 32-bit integer), so it is choosing a port number as it would if you set the port number to `0`.

Comment: Also, have you tried specifying a port number greater than 1024? I think port numbers up through 1024 require special permissions.

Comment: @RonMaupin 1) If you look at [the constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_TcpListener__ctor_System_Net_IPAddress_System_Int32_), it accepts a 32-bit signed port number, and 2) if it was lopping off 16 bits in a conversion, it wouldn't be the lower 16 bits.

Comment: thanks for the replies guys, this was just a simple app for testing, i realize i could have done better but the code is not super relevant, it's just a test so i could open ports as needed. 

i have tried running this on other 2016 machines and it runs fine and opens the ports as needed. this is more of a windows problem rather than a coding problem.

Comment: I'm still curious what happens when you try specifying an unused port number greater than 1024.

Comment: 99% of my tests have been trying to open ports higher than 1024, because the software that's actually having issues is opening them between 12k and 16k. so this same thing happens, no matter the port i choose to open it opens them in the 2k range and opens sequentially regardless of the port i specify.